# Can explorers choose not to move?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

Can explorers choose not to move? So instead of rolling dice or playing an action can a survivor skip their own turn so they don't leave a room? One example would be to stay in the mystic elevator and then each turn use the mystic elevator to travel around the house.

Comment: You should break this up into separate questions for better answers

Comment: I've removed your second and third questions. They don't seem intrinsically related to the one I've left behind, and should be asked separately in their own questions. You can still retrieve their content in your [revision history](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/posts/23755/revisions), which you can access by clicking the 'edited X time ago' link at the bottom center of your post.

Comment: Mind you, the second question about being able to not move monsters may be related, if you believe the same rules may be involved. (I don't play this game.) If it seems intrinsically related - i.e. makes no sense to answer just one and not the other here - add it back. Otherwise, you are requiring people to answer two unrelated questions, which mainly just cheats you out of a good answer if someone knows the answer to one but not the answer to the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can choose not to move. The rules on movement state:

> **Moving**
>
> On your explorer’s turn, you can move up to number of spaces equal to your character’s
> current Speed.

"Up to" includes 0 spaces.

Note that if you stay in the elevator for your entire turn, then the elevator will move again. From the [FAQ](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=ah/faqs/hoth):

> Heroes must roll for their destination floor each time they enter the elevator, or at the end of each entire movement phase that they spend in the elevator without moving.